# При прокрутке страницы до определенного места должна срабатывать анимация, а ее нет. Подскажите что не так делаю?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

задача состоит в том чтобы при прокрутке страницы до нужного нам элемента, начиналась анимация, условия для этого казалось  бы написал, вставляю в условие alert он работает, вставляю функцию - нет. Но вставленная отдельно от условия функция работает.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  var el = document.querySelector('#num');
  if (window.scrollY + window.outerHeight - 350 > el.offsetTop) {
    //если вынести функцию ниже наверх, то она срабатывает.
    //если на ее место вписать alert то он тоже работает.

    $(function() {
      $('#num').animate({
        num: 30
      }, {
        duration: 2500,
        step: function(num) {
          this.innerHTML = (num).toFixed(1) + '%'
        }
      });
    });

  }
});
```

```css
#num {
  margin: 1800px auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 114px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="num"></div>
```

Comment: Но на вашем примере она работает)) Хотя `$(function() {` лишнее как мне кажется

Comment: странно что делает он это с задержкой

Comment: действительно, не понимаю в чем дело может просто оперативная память перегружена была кучей вкладок))) но я почти час потратил на то чтобы понять в чем дело)))

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯     у меня с 30 вкладками все ок

Comment: а не подскажете, как сделать, чтобы в условие не копировать целую функцию, а, допустим, вписать только ее имя, а саму функцию описать отдельно. Я просто только недавно учу. На практике познаю.(встретил проблему- решаю).

Comment: Все что находится между `$(function() {` и `});` выносите в отдельную функцию с именем... а внутри условия уже вызываете эту функцию по имени https://jsfiddle.net/svk6f0dv/